# Nesting properties in a property / Nesting an object in a property

Tags: c#, object, properties

It's a simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere:

Suppose I have a class:

```
public class ControlLoop
{
    public double Setpoint { get; set; }
    public double SetpointHighvalue { get; set; }
    public double SetpointLowvalue { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously the last two properties are related to the first one. I want to reprogram the class so that I can initiate the properties nested like this:

```
ControlLoop loop7a = new ControlLoop()
{
    Setpoint = 7.1,
    Setpoint.Highvalue = 20,
    Setpoint.Lowvalue = -10,
};
```

and use it this:

```
            loop7a.Setpoint = 7.1;
        loop7a.Setpoint.Highvalue = 20;
        loop7a.Setpoint.Lowvalue = -10;
```

Is this somehow possible?

And going a step further, suppose I have two classes:

```
public class ControlLoop
{
    public double Setpoint { get; set; }
    public ValueRanges SetpointLimits { get; set; } = new ValueRanges();
}

public class ValueRanges
{
    public double Highvalue { get; set; }
    public double Lowvalue { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to reprogram it using it like this:

```
ControlLoop loop7a = new ControlLoop()
{
    Setpoint = 7.1,
    Setpoint.SetpointLimits.Highvalue = 20,
    Setpoint.SetpointLimits.Lowvalue = -10,
};
```

It this possible and how?

Update : I worked out the suggestion of  @tetralobita here. It gives the desired results, but is feels that is is a bit 'overprogrammed':

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ControlLoop loop7a = new ControlLoop()
        {
            Setpoint = new DoubleX(3.4)
            {
                PointLimits = new ValueRanges()
                {
                    Highvalue = 30,
                    Lowvalue = -40,
                },
            },
            State = new IntX(1)
            {
                PointLimits = new ValueRanges()
                {
                    Highvalue = 0,
                    Lowvalue = 8,
                },
            },

        };
        loop7a.Setpoint = 7.1;
        loop7a.Setpoint.Value = 7.1;
        loop7a.Setpoint.PointLimits.Highvalue = 20;
        loop7a.Setpoint.PointLimits.Lowvalue = -10;
        loop7a.State = 2;
        loop7a.State.PointLimits.Lowvalue = 0;
        loop7a.State.PointLimits.Highvalue = 10;


    }
}
public class ControlLoop
{
    public DoubleX Setpoint { get; set; }
    public IntX State { get; set; }
}

public class ValueRanges
{
    public Double Highvalue { get; set; }
    public Double Lowvalue { get; set; }

}


public class VariableX
{

    public ValueRanges PointLimits { get; set; } = new ValueRanges()
    {
        Highvalue = 1,
        Lowvalue = -1,
    };



}
public class DoubleX : VariableX
{
    public DoubleX(double d)
    {
        Value = d;
    }

    public Double Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator DoubleX(double v)
    {
        return new DoubleX(v);
    }


}
public class IntX : VariableX
{
    public IntX(int d)
    {
        Value = d;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator IntX(int v)
    {
        return new IntX(v);
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a struct?

Comment: You could do `Setpoint = { Highvalue = 20, Lowvalue = -10 }` if you construct the types correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by overriding `implicit` operator

This is for a `double` numbers

```
class Digit {
    public Digit(double d) {
        Val = d;
    }

    public double Val;

    public static implicit operator double(Digit d) {
        return d.Val;
    }

    public static implicit operator Digit(double d) {
        return new Digit(d);
    }

}
```

And now you can do this `Digit d = 12;`
When you do this, class creates new `Digit` and assign your value to `Val`

Msdn link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed syntax for the ControlLoop (loop7a) is possible in C#, but it feels wrong.

Try this instead:

```
public class SetPoint {
    public double Value {get;set;}
    public double High {get;set;}
    public double Low {get;set;}
}

public class ControlLoop {
    public SetPoint SetPoint {get;set;} 
}
```

and create an instance:

```
ControlPoint loop7a = new ControlPoint() {
    SetPoint = new SetPoint() {
        Value = 1.0,
        High = 9.0,
        Low = 0.32
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right that it feels wrong, but in 99% of the time a programmer that uses the setpoint class he only want to access the value property. So controlloop7.Setpoint=10.3. In an update of this question I worked out the suggestion of @tetralobita , it gives the desired results, but the coding is terrible. I have to decide for myself wheter I use this suggestion or leave it like controlloop7.Setpoint.Value=10.3

Answer (score 1):

```
ControlLoop loop7a = new ControlLoop()
{
    Setpoint = 7.1,
    Setpoint.Highvalue = 20,
    Setpoint.Lowvalue = -10,
};
```

`Setpoint` is a `double`. Doubles don’t have `Highvalue` and `Lowvalue` properties. That makes accessing `Setpoint.Highvalue` and `Setpoint.Lowvalue` impossible.

The same is true with `Setpoint.SetpointLimits.Highvalue` since doubles have no `SetpointLimits` property.

What you could do is something like this:

```
ControlLoop loop7a = new ControlLoop()
{
    Setpoint = new Setpoint(7.1)
    {
        Highvalue = 20,
        Lowvalue = -10,
    },
};
```

If that’s acceptable to you, this is what it could look like:

```
public struct Setpoint
{
     public double Value { get; set; }
     public double Highvalue { get; set; }
     public double Lowvalue { get; set; }

     public Setpoint(double value)
     {
         Value = value;
         Highvalue = 0;
         Lowvalue = 0;
     }
}

public class ControlLoop
{
    public Setpoint Setpoint { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `double` is an alias for `System.Double` so it is an object. In theory it would have been nice to  derive a `DoubleX` class from `Double` , unfortunately  `System.Double` is sealed.

Comment: Even if you could subclass `double`, a double *literal* would still be a `double` and not your `CustomDouble` type. So you will always have to instantiate that type, whether it derives from `double` or not.